# Ajax button post in yii

Tags: ajax, yii

Can anyone give example of how to use `CHtml::ajaxbutton` with Yii for posting the elements without form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick Example

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('ButtonName',Yii::app()->createUrl('advert/LoadAdvertFromSay'),
                    array(
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'data'=> 'js:{"data1": val1, "data2": val2 }',                        
                        'success'=>'js:function(string){ alert(string); }'           
                    ),array('class'=>'someCssClass',));
?>
```

**[ajaxSubmitButton()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail)**

You need a `data` parameter inside the `ajaxoptions`

Comment: <?php
                echo Chtml::ajax(array(
                        'url'=>array('advert/LoadAdvertFromSay'),
                        'type'=>'get',
                       'data'=>'js:{id:$("#cateId").val()}',
                        'success'=>"function(string){
                            alert(string);
                            }"
                ));
            ?>
       I call the ajax in button click function.but i couldnt take the data passed in data of ajax.I used $_POST['id'] ,but value is not set for id.how to get value of ajax post.

Comment: In controller action, if (isset($_POST['id'])) ->it return false.Is it correct or not.not mean ,how to get the value of ajax post in controller action.

Comment: Your code have some mistakes, use exactly same as of my example, you used type `get`, change that to `post`, and the first argument must be a string(button name), etc., 1 sec i will update my answer

Comment: in controller you can access the data by `$_POST`

Comment: In view,
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function hello()
        {
           alert("hi");
            <?php
                echo Chtml::ajax(array(
                        'url'=>array('advert/LoadAdvertFromSay'),
                        'type'=>'POST',
                       'data'=>'js:{id:$("#cateId").val()}',
                        'success'=>"function(string){
                            alert(string);
                            }"
                ));
            ?>
        }
    </script>

Comment: <?php echo CHtml::button('Say More', array('class'=>'btnStd','submit' => array('advert/sayMore'),'onclick'=>"hello();"
   )); ?> 
   
   
   In controller action,
   
   public function actionLoadAdvertFromSay() {
 if (isset($_POST['id'])){
  $id=$_POST['id'];
 }
 
$this->redirect(array('loadAdvert', 'id' => $id));
 
 }


}

Comment: @anantha You need a `data` parameter in your ajax array; see my answer.

Comment: @ernie, is it necessary?! when the ajaxsubmit inside form, i think the data parameter is not necessary.. why the down vote?

Comment: Oh he asked without the form..!! oops i missed that, you are right @ernie

Answer (score 4):

To pass the data, you need to add it to your ajax array, e.g.:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('ButtonName',Yii::app()->createUrl('advert/LoadAdvertFromSay'),
                    array(
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'data'=> 'js:$("#dataContainer").serialize()',
                        'success'=>'js:function(string){ alert(string); }'           
                    ),array('class'=>'someCssClass',));
?>
```

In this case, all input type elements in the element with id `dataContainer` would be submitted, and could be accessed via $_POST.

Obviously, the JS could be more complicated, you could get values from certain elements, and build your own object, e.g.:

```
'data' => 'js:{"field1": $("#input1").val(), "pageTitle": $("title").text() }'
```

Then, in your controller, you could access `$_POST["field1"]` and `$_POST["pageTitle"]`, though I generally tend to access items via [CHttpRequest::getParam()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail) as then I can get either POST or GET values, e.g. `CHttpRequest::getParam('field1')`

Answer (score 0):

More [examples of Yii ajax button](http://www.codexamples.com/88/chtml-ajaxbutton/)

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
    $label = 'Click me', 
    $url = '/', 
    $ajaxOptions=array (
        'type'=>'POST',
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'success'=>'function(html){ jQuery("#your_id").html(html); }'
        ), 
    $htmlOptions=array ()
    );

//Output
<a href="#" id="yt0">Click me</a>

<script type="text/script">
    jQuery('body').on('click', '#yt0', function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': function (html) {
                jQuery("#your_id").html(html);
            },
            'url': '/',
            'cache': false,
            'data': jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```