# How to add effect in ajaxSubmitButton yii

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I've created a ajax button in my view, it works fine, when I click on it , the called view is rendered below the button.

How can I add some jquery effect for example like fadeIn  ?

my code is the following

```
<div id="post"> .. </div> 

<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('ButtonName',Yii::app()->createUrl('post/create'),
                    array(
                        'update' => '#post',
                        ),array('class'=>'someCssClass',));

?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the ajaxOptions array.

`ajaxSubmitButton(string $label, mixed $url, array $ajaxOptions=array ( ), array $htmlOptions=array ( ))`

Here is the link to ajax settings at JQuery too

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Thank you for your response but do you have an example of the syntax ?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837333/ajax-button-post-in-yii